# On ValidatesOnExceptions UI is not updating

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, .net-5

Given is an Wpf .Net5.0 Application
with an Resetbutton and Textbox

- Reset set path to Defalut
  `Command="{Binding ResetCommand}" ...  FilePath = @"C:\Temp";`
- Textbox: User can edit Path
  `Text="{Binding FilePath, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"`

  ```
   private string _filePath;

   public string FilePath
   {
       get => _filePath;
       set
       {
           var r = new Regex(@"[\w\s\\.:\-!~]");
           if (r.Matches(value).Count == value.Length)
           {
               SetProperty(ref _filePath, value);
               return;
           }

           throw new ArgumentException("Not an valid windows path");
       }
   }
  ```

When the path is valid I can reset to Default. UI Updates
When user enter an invalid character the border turns red and the Reset button not updating UI.

I try to debug by Snoop and its look like the VM is reseting. But not UI.
What is wrong?

Working Demo: https://github.com/LwServices/WpfValidationDemo/tree/master/ValidationWpf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Simple solution

you can solve it by notifying your UI directly after set the value

```
private void Reset()
{
    FilePath = @"C:\Temp";
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FilePath));
}
```

### reason of the problem

when the `Filepath` is not matching your Regex, you just raise an exception without modifying the value of `_filePath` and it will be always valid path

```
public string FilePath
{
    get => _filePath;
    set
    {
        var r = new Regex(@"[\w\s\\.:\-!~]");
        if (r.Matches(value).Count == value.Length)
        {
            SetProperty(ref _filePath, value); //<<<<<< this will never call if the value passed from the ui doesnot match Regex
            return;
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("Not an valid windows path");
    }
}
```

when you call `reset()` you try to set `Filepath` to **c:/temp**  and if the last value of `_filePath` is equal to **c:/temp** the problem will be appear from the following

```
protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
   if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;  /// your code will return 
   field = value;
   OnPropertyChanged(propertyName); // before notify the UI
   return true;
}
```

so as suggested in the beginning the simple solution is to notify your UI directly **OR** delete the check line from `SetProperty` method

```
if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

its disabling due to missing CanExecute method, use below code

```
    internal class MainWindowViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged {

    private DelegateCommand _resetCmd;
    public ICommand ResetCommand => _resetCmd ?? new DelegateCommand(Reset, canRest);

    

    private string _filePath;

    public string FilePath
    {
        get => _filePath;
        set
        {
            var r = new Regex(@"[\w\s\\.:\-!~]");
            if (r.Matches(value).Count == value.Length)
            {
                SetProperty(ref _filePath, value);
                return;
            }

            throw new ArgumentException("Not an valid windows path");
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
    }

    private void Reset(object obj)
    {
        FilePath = @"C:\Temp";
    }
    private bool canRest() {
        return true;
    }
}
```